How to fix issue with stretched text?
I was testing out the wrapfigure package's compatibility with the tikzpicture environment, and I almost succesfully managed to combine the 2 with the below result:

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig, lipsum, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{block7/.style={ rectangle, draw=red, line width=0.5mm, fill=orange!20, minimum height=1cm, text width=4cm, text centered }}
\tikzset{arrow4/.style={green!50!black, -{Stealth[orange, length=5mm]}, line width=0.5mm, line cap =round, text = blue }}

\begin{document}

\noindent Normally, text is placed below a figure, table, tikzpicture etc. when you close the environment and continue writing afterwards. This can leave quite a lot of blank space, however, depending on the size of the figure. Fortunately, this problem can be overcome by utilizing the \verb|wrapfigure|-environment which allows for wrapping text around figures. An example of this is provided below:
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[block7] (QuestionP) {What's the formula for pythagoras?};
    \node[block7, below left = of QuestionP, xshift=2cm] (ans1) {\(a + b = c\)}; 
    \node[block7, below right = of QuestionP, xshift=-2cm] (ans2) {\(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\)};
    \draw[arrow4] (QuestionP.west) -| node[above=0.05cm]{Option a} (ans1);
    \draw[arrow4] (QuestionP.east) -| node[above=0.05cm]{Option b} (ans2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

The problem is that the text before the wrapfigure environment gets stretched if the text doesn't naturally extend to the end of the width of the page. A "quickfix" I found was to add \\[-0.5cm] right after the stretched text, but it doesn't seem like the correct or consistent solution since the placement is done manually. Is there a proper way to solve this problem?

You can leave a blank line (in your code) right before the figure, instructing TeX that you want a paragraph there, so that it ends the line without extending it. Of course, if you do not really want a paragraph and you happen to have indented paragraphs, you can employ \noindent in the text after the figure.
Quoting from the wrapfig manual:
It is convenient to begin the environment between paragraphs, but if you want
placement in the middle of a paragraph, you must put the environment between
two words where there is a natural line break.

Oh wow, sometimes the answer really is simpler than expected. I almost feel embarrassed I asked now. Thanks for the clear solution!
